# SQL is Giving the Error: ORA-00909: Invalid Number of Arguments

Tags: oracle

I have two errors in my queries places check my queries right or wrong I'm new to Oracle so don't mind

Here is the SQL

SQL is Giving the Error: `ORA-00909: Invalid Number of Arguments`

```
CREATE VIEW order_summery
AS
SELECT o.id,
    o.order_date,(cu.first_name||' '|| cu.last_name) as customer_name
    ,Sum(NVL(p.price,0)) as total_amount
    ,Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)) as discount_amount
    ,NVL(Sum(NVL(p.price,0),0)) - NVL(Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)),0) as final_amount
FROM tbl_order o
INNER JOIN tbl_customer cu on o.customer_id = cu.id
INNER JOIN tbl_order_item oi on o.id= oi.order_id
INNER JOIN tbl_product p on oi.product_id= p.id;
```

```
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

```
CREATE VIEW sales_report
AS
SELECT o.id,
    ,o.order_date
    ,(cu.first_name||' '|| cu.last_name) as customer_name,
    ,Sum(NVL(p.price,0)) as total_amount
    ,Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)) as discount_amount
    ,NVL(Sum(NVL(p.price,0),0)) - NVL(Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)),0) as final_amount
    ,CASE o.is_deliverd WHEN 'y' THEN 'Deliverd'  ELSE 'Not Deliverd' END as status    
FROM tbl_order o
INNER JOIN tbl_customer cu on o.customer_id = cu.id
INNER JOIN tbl_order_item oi on o.id= oi.order_id
INNER JOIN tbl_product p on oi.product_id= p.id;
```

Comment: your 2nd last `)` is not at proper place - `NVL(Sum(NVL(p.price,0),0))`. Just remove the outer `NVL` you don't need it

Comment: In the first: your parentheses are misplaced, giving `SUM` two arguments instead of `NVL`. In the second: you have an extraneous comma after `o_id`. You don't really need to know any Oracle to find these problems. If the query is too big/complicated to find the exact problem, use divide and conquer: delete stuff until you've found the smallest thing that gives the same problem. By that point it'll usually stare you in the face, if not, start adding whitespace and indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is here `(Sum(NVL(p.price,0),0))` Also I guess you need to use group by function because you have sum. and no need for nvl in the sum.

```
CREATE VIEW order_summery
AS
SELECT o.id,
    o.order_date,(cu.first_name||' '|| cu.last_name) as customer_name
    ,Sum(NVL(p.price,0)) as total_amount
    ,Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)) as discount_amount
    ,Sum(NVL(p.price,0)) - Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)) as final_amount
FROM tbl_order o
INNER JOIN tbl_customer cu on o.customer_id = cu.id
INNER JOIN tbl_order_item oi on o.id= oi.order_id
INNER JOIN tbl_product p on oi.product_id= p.id
group by o.id, o.order_date ,cu.first_name,cu.last_name ;
```

as for the second query remove the  `,` after the id

```
o.id,
    ,
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, i tried your query after that im getting this error "SQL Error: ORA-00904: "P"."DISCOUNT_AMOUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier""

Comment: @user3837868 well in the table `tbl_product` do you have column called `discount_amount`?

Comment: sorry sir my column name is discount i changed every discount_amount as a discount after that i getting this error " SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function" sorry to ask many questions

Comment: @user3837868 its ok i am here to help you, as I covered in my answer that you have to add group by at the end of the query. check the query I mentionned in my answer

Comment: error "SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @user3837868 check now my edit then try and tell me if it worked

Comment: OMG! you are my god finally worked thank you. pls check 2nd one also

Answer (score 0):

Fix final_amount parameter (one NVL function only needed):

```
,Sum(NVL(p.price,0)) - Sum(NVL(p.discount_amount,0)) as final_amount
```